# MongoDB $addToSet to deep nested array of object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Below is my data structure.

```
{
    "_id" : "room1",
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "member1",
            "name" : "Michael",
            "payments" : [
                {
                    "month": "2018/09"
                    "amount": "20"
                }
            ]
        }, 
    ]
}
```

I want to push below object to Michael's `payments`

```
{ 
  "month": "2018/09", 
  "amount": "5000" 
}
```

In this case, What I want to is overwrite object, because `month: "2018/09"` already exist. Like below :

```
{
    "_id" : "room1",
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "member1",
            "name" : "Michale",
            "payments" : [
                {
                    "month": "2018/09"
                    "amount": "5000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
    ]
}
```

And, In case when I want to push object that not exist same `month` in payments, I want to add this object to `payments`.

```
{ 
  "month": "2018/10", 
  "amount": "2000" 
}
```

So the expected result is

```
{
    "_id" : "room1",
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "member1",
            "payments" : [
                {
                    "month": "2018/09"
                    "amount": "5000"
                },
                {
                    "month": "2018/10"
                    "amount": "2000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
    ]
}
```

---

I tried like below, but it's not working. My code generate duplicated new `month` object every time I tried. How can I do this properly?

```
Rooms.update(
    {
        _id: "room1",
        "members._id": "member1",
        "members.$.payments": {
            $not: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    month: req.body.month
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            "members.$.payments": {
                month: req.body.month,
                amount: req.body.value
            }
        }
    },
    { multi: true }, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result)
    }
)
```

Comment: use `$ne` instead of `$not` here... `"members.$.payments": {
            $elemMatch: {
                month: { $ne: req.body.month }
            }
        }`

Comment: Get rid of $ in the `members.$.payments` in query part.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I plused you guys's suggetion but still not working... It is not generated duplicated object anymore, but it's not overwrite.

Comment: @Veeram Thanks, I removed it. but it's still not working -- no more duplicated object, but not overwrited

Comment: That is working as expected. $addToSet doesn't overwrite the element.

Comment: I need overwrite and push both.

Comment: You have to use two queries. $set query when you want to overwrite and push query when you want to add.

Comment: @Veeram Okay. Thanks. I understand. I will add my code to answer, but I don't know how to `set` ... T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I heard I have to determine duplication myself, so below is my code... it's writing now.,,

---

So Finally this is my code

```
  Clubs.findOne({ 
        uid: req.params.club_id,
        "members._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.member_uid)
    }, function(err, club){

        let member = club.members.filter(el => {
            if(el._id.equals(req.params.member_uid)) return el
        })

        let duplicated = false; 
        member[0].payments.map(el => {
            if(el.month === req.body.month) duplicated = true
        })

       if(duplicated){

        Clubs.update(
            {
                uid: req.params.club_id,
                "members._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.member_uid),
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    ["members.$.payments."+index+".amount"] : req.body.value
                }
            },
            function (err, result, third) {
                if (err) throw err
                console.log('result')
                console.log(result)
                res.json({})
            }
        )


    } else {

        Clubs.update(
            {
                uid: req.params.club_id,
                "members._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.member_uid),
            },
            {
                $push: {
                    "members.$.payments" : { 
                        month : req.body.month, 
                        amount: req.body.value 
                    }
                }
            },
            function (err, result, third) {
                if (err) throw err
                console.log('result')
                console.log(result)
                res.json({})
            }
        )
    }

    })
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use below command to add without duplicity either in months or amount

```
Rooms.update(
    {
        _id: "room1",
        "members._id": "member1"
    },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            "members.$.payments": {
                month: req.body.month,
                amount: req.body.value
            }
        }
    },function (err, result) {
        console.log(result)
    }
)
```

Comment: Have you red my question... your answer will generate duplicated object.

Comment: No it's not i was checked it locally

Comment: This is the same as what Juntae wrote in his original post. This results in the error 'The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query'.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider **changing the structure** of your nested array to an **object**? So change this

```
{
  "payments": [{
      "month": "2018/09"
      "amount": "5000"
    },
    {
      "month": "2018/10"
      "amount": "2000"
    }
  ]
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "payments": {
    "2018/09": "5000",
    "2018/10": "2000"
  }
}
```

Then you can do a simple update:

```
Rooms.update({
    _id: "room1",
    "members._id": "member1",
    "members.payments": {
      $exists: true
    }
  }, {
    $set: {
      "members.payments." + req.body.month: req.body.value
    }
  },

)
```